# Перечисление в предложении

Tags: грамотная-речь

Корректно ли перечислить проблемы так: «Изучая данную дисциплину, обучаемые сталкиваются с проблемой достаточно большого количества источников, постоянно меняющегося законодательства, поиска нужного нормативного акта, сложностью в толковании и применении положений закона»?

Answer (score 1):

Грамматических нарушений здесь нет. Стилистически - тяжеловато читается. И, наверное, "проблем**ами**" и "... сложност**ями** толкова**ния** и примене**ния** положений..."